# Eclipse RCP - Modal dialog not on top in Linux

Tags: eclipse, dialog, modal-dialog

We have developed an Eclipse RCP. One of the dialogs (Jface dialog) is not appearing to be modal in Linux. There is another similar Jface dialog in the same RCP that works as modal.

Can anyone help me in this regard. I tried debugging and confirmed that the style of both the dialogs are same and parent shell is set as same for both.

I couldn't figure out why this dialog is not modal, whereas the other one appears fine. In Windows, both of them work fine as modal dialogs.

I am using Ubuntu(32 bit) for testing this.

Thanks in advance